# Unable to retrieve secrets from Azure KV via Azure functions app

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

Have the following code to retrieve the secrets from KV using azure functions but when I run test/run, I keep getting 401 unauthorized. I have changed identify to system defined and assigned the generated service principal access to get, list secerets. I have also set auth level to anonymous. What else could be wrong?

```
import os
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

def get_secret_from_azure_key_vault():
    # Create a credential object from managed identity, environment variables, or Azure CLI
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

    # Create a secret client
    client = SecretClient(vault_url="https://test1.vault.azure.net", credential=credential)

    # Get the secret value
    secret = client.get_secret("testsecret")

    return secret.value

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    
    secret_value = get_secret_from_azure_key_vault()

    return func.HttpResponse(f"The secret value is: {secret_value}.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code and was able to retrieve the secret from the Key Vault.

**Code :**

```py
import os
import logging
import azure.functions as func  
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

def get_secret_from_azure_key_vault():
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    client = SecretClient(vault_url="https://<keyvault_name>.vault.azure.net/", credential=credential)
    secret = client.get_secret("<secret_name>")
    return secret.value

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    secret_value = get_secret_from_azure_key_vault()
    return func.HttpResponse(f"The secret value is: {secret_value}.")
```

**requirements.txt :**

```py
azure-functions
azure-identity
azure-keyvault-secrets
```

I enabled the **identity** in the function app as below:

[image]

I gave access to the function app to retrieve the secret from the key vault as below:

[image]

**Output :**

It runs successfully as below,

[image]
[image]

I retrived the secret from key vault with the above output **URL** in the browser as below:

[image]

Then, I deployed the above code to the function app as below,

[image]

**Azure Portal :**

The function code runs successfully and retrieves the secret from the key vault as below.

[image]